# Executing Javascript from inside textarea (custom JS console)

Tags: javascript, textarea, eval

I am interested in building a text editor in a CMS backend that allows users to write Javascript into a textarea and test it while editing.

The closest I can think of is something like.

```
document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://site.com/file.js';
```

But instead of

```
.src='http://site.com/file.js';
```

I would need to fill the script element with the textarea value. Does anyone have any idea as how to handle something like this?

Comment: You would need to perform an ajax request to retrieve the js file from the server, and the callback would dump the contents into the textarea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written a simple one of these myself (doesn't work in IE) here: http://phrogz.net/tmp/simplejs.html

Comment: Nice job, do you see any major reason that I could not convert this into jQuery? Maybe with jQuery syntax it could be cross browser compatible?

Comment: No, there's no reason this shouldn't be cross-browser. In fact, it is the parts of the page unrelated to the actual evaluation that break IE. Thanks to this question, I now have the impetus after 10 years to fix it to work with IE again :)

Comment: Thanks, and I love the 'Live' feature.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The key element there for me was the `try...catch` around the `eval`. I was using `eval` with `eslint-disable` but no luck.. Surrounding it with try catch did it!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function.

```
 eval(document.getElementById('wmd-input').value);
```

And if you're going to let users enter JavaScript into your CMS, be sure you're up to speed on [cross-site scripting (XSS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but am going to have to give the answer to Phrogz since he was the first to answer and show me working code. And it is not going to be my CMS others put Javascript into, but a CMS others can use on their own site to put JS into their own site (using CodeIgniter that has XSS built into its DB Class).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make an ajax call to load the page. I'd recommend JQuery, which makes it very easy, and there are plenty of examples on their site.

It would look something like this:

```
$.get('http://site.com/file.j', function(data) {
    $('#txta').text(data);
});
```

Where 'txta' is the id of the textarea.

If you want to execute the script in the browser, you can use the javascript eval() function - but I would exercise extreme caution with this approach since it can lead to all sorts of security flaws, including cross-site scripting attacks.