# How to take html script from text form and execute it in a new window?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I am trying to make HTML and JavaScript executor but I don't know how to take text from text form and execute it in a new window. Like in w3schools.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing Javascript from inside textarea (custom JS console)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875446/executing-javascript-from-inside-textarea-custom-js-console)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TCnG4/1/   look here I've created fiddle for you
Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

They way w3schools does it is they POST the data from the text frame and then in the second frame, it runs the page as a document.

On clicking submit, you could then change the `contentWindow.document` value to equal the HTML that the user entered