# htaccess rewriterule ignore index.html

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-2

I'm using CodeIgniter and `.htaccess` to rewrite the URLs but I want it to ignore `index.html`.

This is so we can upload an `index.html` at any time as this will be a temporary landing page. With a link through to the main site on the `index.php`.

This is what is currently in `.htaccess` and I have set the server's directory index to `index.html index.php`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.html|index\.php|js|img|fonts|data|css|uploaded|mobile_devices|audioplayer|emails|robots\.txt|archive_blog)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

that rather looks like you want to rewrite everything that does not really exist in your directory.

try this instead of your current RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using RewriteCond to ignore the index.html file, you could instead restrict access to it directly through using the FilesMatch directive. FilesMatch accepts a regular expression which could filter based on file name (e.g., index.html) or any regular expression.

Blocking access to the index.html file

```
<FilesMatch "index\.html$">
    Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
```

That would completely deny access to the index.html file. I will admit, that I do not know the negative effects this would have on search engine crawling.

To read more about the FilesMatch Directive see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch

---

As for the rest of the directories in that list you currently have, you could just lock down all directory access regardless of name. It would give you a little more coverage going forward.

```
Options -Indexes
```

To read more about the Options Directive see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options

---

In the end your new .htaccess file would look something like this:

```
# Protect specific files from access
<FilesMatch "index\.html$">
    Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Hide directory listing for URL's mapping to a directory
Options -Indexes

# Follow all symbolic links in this directory 
Options +FollowSymLinks

# General rewrite rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the built in [environment](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html) function?

You could create a 'maintenance' environment and set the base controller to whatever you want. Then you would just need to edit the index.php file to specify the environment you want.