# curl more than 300 times slower than node-fetch?

Tags: node.js, bash, networking, fetch-api

I'm writing a script to scan the `/config` route on some ports on a host.

I have first written the script in `node.js` and am now porting it to `bash` to achieve less dependencies.

Why is the bash script more than 300 times slower when scanning `localhost`. What am I missing?

I guess there are some optimizations built in `node-fetch`. How can I achieve the same in bash?

- node.js: 10 Ports -> 79ms
- bash(0.0.0.0): 10 Ports -> 2149ms
- bash(localhost): 10 Ports -> 25156ms

I found out that in `bash` when using `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`, it is only 27 times slower, but still... (In `node.js`, using `0.0.0.0` does not make a significant difference.)

node.js *(IFFE omitted for readability)*

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
for (let port = portFrom; port <= portTo; port++) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost" + port + '/config');
    const json = await res.json();
    console.log(json);
  } catch {/*no-op*/}
}
```

bash

```bash
for ((port=$port_from; port<=$port_to; port++))
  do
    json="$(curl -s http://localhost:$port/config)"
    echo "$json"
done
```

Comment: You are missing for example, that in the `bash` variant you are creating and terminating a new process in the OS every time. That's quite expensive on the OS level. With `node` you only start a process once and then do everything else within this process ...

Comment: Not entirely sure with the last measurement. This problably has some other reason. Ten calls of `curl` shouldn't take 25 seconds ... How often did you repeat those tests?

Comment: And just as a sidemark: using `0.0.0.0` as a *target*  for your request doesn't make much sense. It might be resolved to localhost on linux systems. But technically `0.0.0.0` is only supported as a *source address* when binding a socket to an interface of the machine ...

Comment: Ah okay, so what is `node` then actually doing in the background? I thought it would just call `curl` or `wget` or something similar? Is it also possible to achieve this with bash or with something else without many requirements in a docker container environment?
I just repeated the last measurements and it took 4m8,748s for 100 calls. Note however that the call will fail/timeout most of the time.
Do you have any idea why it takes so much longer when using `localhost`?

Comment: For doing multiple requests with curl see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110444/how-can-i-run-multiple-curl-requests-processed-sequentially  Any particular reason you are insisting on using a technically invalid address? If you want to connect to `localhost` use either `localhost` or the defined IP address `127.0.0.1`

Comment: If most of your requests run into a timeout, it's no wonder that it takes quite an amount of time. Hard to say why, without knowing your environment